# Flutter Error [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Facing this issue [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

after adding the  same still not working

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'Screens/HomePage.dart';

 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
    }

       class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
         @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
        title: "FireBase Database",
     theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomePage(),
            );
         }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**make sure** that you have already imported GoogleService-Info.plist file For IOS and 'google-services.json' file for Android.

Then try **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get**.

Comment: I did that,the file is in andriod/app folder

Comment: please check if you are installing your Firebase configuration file, 
like here: 
"https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/android/#installing-your-firebase-configuration-file"